# What is involved in a Mental Competency Evaluation in the criminal justice system?

Tags: social-psychology, forensic-psychology

I am very curious as to what exactly is done during a mental competency evaluation. (Not too sure if this is a good question for this forum- apologies if not!) In this instance, a criminal defendant in Tennessee will go through this process as the preliminary hearing has been delayed about 3.5 months.

From what I understand, the defendant will be transported from the county jail on a daily/weekly basis to undergo this evaluation. This will be used to see if the defendant is mentally competent to actually stand trial if it goes that far (i.e. if the defendant does not take a plea bargain).

I'm just curious as to what questions are asked, what methods are used, who conducts the evaluation, and how the information is presented once the preliminary hearing actually rolls around.